# Update making any/all emails sound notification

Tags: sound, ubuntu-touch, email, notification, phone

I am using BQ Aquaris 4.5. I updated my phone yesterday when prompted. I have a problem now. I use Gmail, I only used to get notifications for emails coming into my "primary" tab. Now with the update I get a notification for each & every email.

I have subscribed to some YouTube channels, forums etc and I am getting loads of emails & notifications in, and they are clogging up my notification space on phone and also I get the sound every five minutes.

Anyone got an idea how to only get notifications for primary again?

Comment: One developer suggested this workaround: https://lists.launchpad.net/ubuntu-phone/msg19569.html . Although some users reported this to be ineffective for them.

Comment: Cheers @pomsky for the reply. I tried the suggestions but it does not help. As you can imagine, with my subscriptions I'm getting notifications constantly, really frustrating.

Comment: I created a bugreport for this: https://bugs.launchpad.net/webapps-core/+bug/1585997 It would help if everyone who has issues with this behavior marked themselves as "also affected".

Answer (score 0):

It seems after OTA-10, users would get notifications for all the mails landing in inbox. So an obvious workaround to get notifications only for "primary" emails is to make others skip inbox. You might want to try this workaround. You'll get almost everything as before except the tabbed inbox feature.

**Step 1:**

Open Gmail in browser and go to *cogwheel* > *Settings* > *Labels* tab and create a new label
[image: crate new label]
**Step 2:**

Name the new label *Promotions*
[image: promo label]

**Step 3:**

Now go to *Filters and Blocked Addresses* tab and create a new filter

[image: create filter]
**Step 4:**

In *Includes the words* field enter *category:promotions* and then *Create filter with this search*

[image: category]

**Step 5:**

Check the boxes titled *Skip the Inbox (Archive it)*, *Apply the label:* and select *Promotions* and then *Create filter*

[image: skip inbox & label]

**Step6:**

You will see the label *Promotions* appearing in the side menu and from now on all your incoming mails in promotions category will skip inbox and land here

[image: label at sidebar]

**Step 7:**

Now repeat the process for other categories, e.g. *Social, Updates* etc.